# Create web services and APIs to query and CRUD processes from Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: web-services, web, crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have been developing MS Dynamics CRM - as our central application - for 1+ years with MS Dynamics SDK and dedicated tools to query from MS Dynamics CRM database.

We have also one mobile application and web site which we need to get information from our MS Dynamics CRM database. I don't want to use MS's own Dynamics CRM SDK to create this data communication with our web site and mobile application.

Is it possible to create a fully independent (such nodejs, laravel etc.) to directly query and CRUD processes from MS Dynamics CRM database, without using MS own tools/SDKs?

Thank you

Comment: Any interation with Dynmaics not through the official SDK/API wouldn't be supported and would likey result in inconsistent data. Why don't you want to use the supported API ?

Comment: frankly speaking, the existing database is quite old and don't have the data-map. It's almost impossible to find the required relations of tables-rows-columns-data. We have to use this database since we have not completed to build the new one (an open source platform) therefore we need to build the services on the MS Dynamics CRM Database :( I can access the database and can see the tables with contents. But I agree with you that platform has some complex methods to CRUD any data. Looks like I am desperate

Comment: Are you saying the current database is no longer supported and you're happy to take the risk? Almost any language can run a SQL statement , so yes you can build your own API

Comment: Not happy but mandatory to take the risk, since the existing CRM is not fully functional, just matching the essential needs of our company